# Elasticsearch - Find documents missing two fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to create a query that returns information about how many documents that don't have data for two fields (date.new and date.old). I have tried the query below, but it works as OR-logic, where all documents missing either date.new or date.old are returned. Does anyone know how I can make this only return documents missing both fields?

```
{
   "aggs":{
      "Missing_field_count1":{
         "missing":{
            "field":"date.new"
         }
      },
      "Missing_field_count2":{
         "missing":{
            "field":"date.old"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregations is not the feature to use for this. You need to use the [`exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query wrapped within a [`bool/must_not`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query, like this:

```
GET index/_count
{
  "size": 0,
  "bool": {
    "must_not": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "date.new"
        }
      },
      {
        "exists": {
          "field": "date.old"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I think I might was unclear in my initial question, but I only want data about how many documents are missing both those fields, not to get the actual documents returned. I'm new to elasticsearch, so I'm a bit lost :/

Comment: See my updated answer, you simply need to hit the `_count` endpoint to get what you want.

Comment: Yes, this solved my question! Thank you for the good explanation

Answer (score 2):

[hits.total.value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response) indicates the count of the documents that match the search request. The value indicates the number of hits that match and relation indicates whether the value is accurate (eq) or a lower bound (gte)

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "new": 1501,
    "old": 10
  }
}

{
  "title": "elasticsearch"
}

{
  "title": "elasticsearch-query"
}
{
  "date": {
    "new": 1400
  }
}
```

**The search query given by @Val answers on how to achieve your use case.**

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,                <-- note this
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65112793",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "elasticsearch"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65112793",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "elasticsearch-query"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Using the `_count` endpoint is better, especially in the case where there are more than 10000 hits